# Cortana weather forecast in Celsius

Tags: 8.1, cortana

How to switch Cortana to show weather forecast in Celsius instead of Fahrenheit? I thought changing it in Bing Weather will affect Cortana, but she doesn't want to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cortana learns as it goes. What worked well for me was asking for weather in Celsius in my questions and after a while ( I think 7 - 9 responses) she started to provide the weather in Celsius by default.

Other users reported that they asked her to "show temperature in Celcius by default" and she made it default. But only until Cortana quits, than she forgot so it seems like my approach works a bit better

Comment: I use to ask the weather and after ask "what about in Celsius". She still doesn't remember. In you case she remember even when you just open her tile?

Comment: I think she has a Short Term Memory Loss. :D I keep asking almost everyday "What is the current forecast in Celsius?". Still she does not remember.

Comment: This has not worked for me.  I've done it more than 50 times.

Answer (score 3):

This is down to location and region settings.  Because US is the only supported region, it get's the default for that location from each new instance of starting up Cortana.  No amount of asking for the temperature in other scales works for, despite many requests for it in an attempt to *teach* it, although I was pleased to note it's currently 295 Kelvin...

Answer (score 1):

She's way to awesome
.. U ask her the temperature in Celsius about 7-8 times, she'll set that as default. A good and a quick learner, something to learn from her.